# How to position before and after pseudo elements to center-right and center-left of their parent?

Tags: css, sass, absolute

I've been in the process of making a customise-able tooltip for Vue using SCSS, allowing a developer to specify the colour and placement of the tooltip, which is constructed from a pair of ::before and ::after pseudo-elements in a button element of variable size. The ::before acts as the tooltip's arrow, and the ::after the tooltip content.

There's four placements I want to make possible: top, bottom, left and right. The following two groups of classes apply to the top and bottom positions:

```
    .tooltip-placement-top, .triangle-placement-top {
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }

    .tooltip-placement-top {
      bottom: calc(100% + 10px);  // 3. 100% here is parent height, key point
    }

    .triangle-placement-top {
      bottom: calc(100%); // 4. no need add 5px, because transparent border also takes place
      border-top-color: var(--tooltip-border-color);
    }

    .tooltip-placement-bottom, .triangle-placement-bottom {
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }

    .tooltip-placement-bottom {
      top: calc(100% + 10px);  // 3. 100% here is parent height, key point
    }

    .triangle-placement-bottom {
      top: calc(100%);
      border-bottom-color: var(--tooltip-border-color);
    }
```

and these result in a centred tooltip above and below the button like so:
[image]
The next stage is to position the left and right hand tooltip classes to sit aligned with the horizontal centre of the button, but conforming to the left or right edge of the button rather than the top and bottom, as seen here:
[image]

Both the button and tooltip are likely to appear as different sizes depending on their context of use, so unfortunately this needs to be a scalable solution (i.e. increasing the size of either button or tooltip won't cause them to fall out of alignment). My current attempts to adapt the code has made the tooltip appear at 100% of its own width right of the button, which as you can imagine looked terrible.

Sorry I don't have screen-caps to share, but I hope the drawings make it clear what I'm trying to achieve! If you need any additional code then I can supply it, but the question was getting quite bulky as it is.

Comment: You don't seem to be using css-positioning even though you have included this in your tagging. I'd start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it!

Here's what I have for my right and left classes:

```
.tooltip-placement-left, .triangle-placement-left {
    top: 50%;
}
.tooltip-placement-left {
    right: 100%;
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: translate(-12px, -50%);
}
.triangle-placement-left {
    right: 100%;
    transform: translate(8.3px, -50%);
}
.tooltip-placement-right, .triangle-placement-right {
    top: 50%;
}
.tooltip-placement-right {
    left: 100%;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: translate(12px, -50%);
}
.triangle-placement-right {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-8.3px, -50%);
}
```

the exact distances in pixels depend on the dimensions of your tooltip arrow, but this is what worked for me. Hope it helps someone else!